# Why is copper discharged in the electrolysis of copper (II) sulphate solution instead of hydrogen?

Tags: electrolysis

In the electrolysis of copper (II) sulphate with graphite electrodes, I am confused why copper ions are discharged and form copper metal at the cathode. As far as I know hydrogen ions have a lower position than copper ions in the electrochemical series, and so technically shouldn't hydrogen be discharged due to its stronger oxidizing power compared to copper?

Comment: The site expects that you write explicit compact summary of your prior effort to answer the question, based on your knowledge and on searching for existing related  info or answers. It would prevent others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself.

Comment: Should be aluminium discharged  before hydrogen?

Comment: No? Because aluminum is a weaker oxidizing agent?

Comment: Metallic aluminium is stronger reducer than hydrogen, while aluminium ions are weaker oxidizer than hydrogen ions.

Comment: So as copper ions are have stronger reducing power , it has less tendency to gain electrons compared to hydrogen, so why is copper discharged?

Comment: They do not. To what would you oxidize copper(II) ions? You should get your knowledge base straight before making conclusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is the contrary of what you state. $\ce{H2}$ has a stronger **reducing** power than $\ce{Cu}$ (and not a stronger oxidizing power)